# How can you create a custom Facebook "Like" button?

Tags: facebook

Does anyone know if there's a way to use a custom LIKE button and make calls to the facebook like api on the server side? Ideally I'd like to have my own LIKE button that calls my app and also calls out to FB like.

For instance Pandora seems to do this with their "thumbs" up button.
I know they were a launch partner so they may have special treatment.

thx!

Comment: I know this is OLD but I want to know with the new method if there is a way to create a custom button or use a different image but the same action as (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) anyone???

Comment: @matt Please see my answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is still impossible to do.

Pandora definitely has special treatment (instant personalization). Quora is also on whatever whitelist allows you to make a custom like button.

Though, I can appreciate that this could be easily abused.

Answer (score 2):

The like button isn't generically customizable. Some companies partner with Facebook and get the ability to customize it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can! All you have to do is use whatever image you want e.g.:

`<img src="custom-facebook-image.png" />`

And then link it to the Facebook Share URL as follows:

`http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://www.example.com&t=CustomTitle`

Just make sure you escape all the characters in the URL and you can add it as a href:

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://www.example.com&t=CustomTitle">
    <img src="custom-facebook-image.png" />
</a>
```

Comment: To be clear, "Sharing" and "Liking" on Facebook are not the same thing.

Comment: Very true - but this is the closest we can get ;)